# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, sql, string, casting, double

```
SqlDataReader reader;

String sqlreadcom = "SELECT Balance FROM IncomeGenerator";

using (reader = new SqlCommand(sqlreadcom,sqlCon).ExecuteReader())
{
   if(reader.HasRows)
   {
      while(reader.Read())
      {
         String value = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Balance"));
         txtbalance.Text = Convert.ToString(value);
      }
   }
}
```

My `Balance` field data type is `float`. I need to convert it to string.

This is the message I'm getting

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Double' to type
>   'System.String'

Can someone guide me to make this error free

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try it with

```
object value = reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("Balance"));
txtbalance.Text = value.ToString();
```

If there are many rows to read, you should do the `GetOrdinal` outside of the loop like

```
int idxBalance = reader.GetOrdinal("Balance");
```

and use `idxBalance` later.

Answer (score 3):

You should use

```
double val = reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("Balance"));
```

and convert it simply:

```
txtbalance.Text = val.ToString();
```

**Edit:**
When I see your code again(if you change it as bellow):

```
  while(reader.Read())
  {
     var val = reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("Balance"));
     txtbalance.Text = val.ToString();
  }
```

what's the purpose of UI update in each iteration? user can't see anything in this case, in `txtbalance.Text = val.ToString();` You just showing last record value. So instead of fetching `n` item from DB, in your query do some sort of order and just show first item.

Comment: Dont you see that "valu" variable is declared as String ?

Comment: @HABJAN, I'd answer in editor, and forgot about it, fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Read it is `float` first:

```
float value = reader.GetFloat(reader.GetOrdinal("Balance"));
```

and then `ToString()` it:

```
txtbalance.Text = value.ToString();
```

and if you want you can format it (example with [currency format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)):

```
txtbalance.Text = value.ToString("C");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `reader["Balance"].ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 txtbalance.Text= value.toString();
```